# Passbook development on Windows

Tags: macos, windows-7, ios6, passbook

I went through this tutorial for basic Passbook dev:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1

I will be using a Windows machine for development and I see two Apple specific tools used:

1. OpenSSL commands - this one I believe there is a Windows version for, so it's doable.
2. Keychain - for storing, importing, and exporting certificates. Is there a Windows alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to Passbook working with the help of this gentleman's code:

https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook

He also has a very useful translation of how to get the certificates running along nicely:

http://www.tomasmcguinness.com/2012/06/28/generating-an-apple-ios-certificate-using-windows/

Thanks to Tomas McGuinness!

Comment: You're very welcome! I'm glad you found my library useful. If you have any suggestions for improvements, please let me know.

Comment: I'm about to embark on this process and also came across dotnet-passbook. Wish me luck